# First number that divides all numbers (1,2,...,100)

Tags: algorithm, math, calculator, division

Given that the first number to divide all (1,2,..,10) is 2520.
And given that the first number to divide all (1,2,..,20) is  232792560.
Find the first number to divide all (1,2,..,100).  (all consecutive numbers from 1 to 100).
The answer should run in less than a minute.

I'm writing the solution in Java, and I'm facing two problems:

1. How can I compute this is the solution itself is a number so huge that cannot be handled?
   I tried using "BigInteger" by I'm doing many additions and divisions and I don't know if this is increasing my time complexity.
2. How can I calculate this in a less than a minute? The solution I though about so far haven't even stopped.

This is my Java code (using big integers):

```
public static boolean solved(int start, int end, BigInteger answer) {
    for (int i=start; i<=end; i++) {
        if (answer.mod(new BigInteger(valueOf(i))).compareTo(new BigInteger(valueOf(0)))==0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger answer = new BigInteger("232792560");
    BigInteger y = new BigInteger("232792560");
    while(!solved(21,100, answer)) {
        answer = answer.add(y);
    }
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

I take advantage of the fact that I know already the solution for (1,..,20).

Currently is simply not stopping.

I though I could improve it by changing the function `solved` to check for only values we care about.

```
For example:
100 = 25,50,100
99  = 33,99
98 = 49,98
97 = 97
96 = 24,32,48,96
```

And so on. But, this simple calculation of identifying the smallest group of number needed has become a problem itself to which I didn't look for / found a solution. Of course, the time complexity should stay under a minute either case.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Why do you write that 5250 is the first number to divide 1...10? Is it not the other way around, that 5210 is divisible by the numbers in the range 1...10?.

Comment: The smallest number divisible by all integers from 1 to 10 is [**2520**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2520_(number))

Comment: In Python, finding the number for n = 100 or even n = 10,000 is almost instantaneous (using the LCM approach). You should have no problem in getting under the 1-minute mark with Java.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: it ain't what you don't know that kills you - it's "what you know" that just ain't so. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first number that can be divided by all elements of some set (which is what you have there, despite the slightly different formulation) is also known as the [Least Common Multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of that set. `LCM(a, b, c) = LCM(LCM(a, b), c)` and so on, so in general, it can be computed by taking *n - 1* pairwise LCMs where *n* is the number of items in the set. `BigInteger` does not have an `lcm` function, but the LCM can be computed via `a * b / gcd(a, b)` so in Java with `BigInteger`:

```
static BigInteger lcm(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
    return a.multiply(b).divide(a.gcd(b));
}
```

For 1 to 20, computing the LCM in that way indeed results in 232792560. It's easy to do it up to 100 too.

Comment: Maybe not necessary if this is fast enough, but you only need to consider maximal prime powers in the range.

Answer (score 3):

Find all max prime powers in your range and take their product.

E.g. 1-10: 2^3, 3^2, 5^1, 7^1: product is 2520, which is the right answer (not 5250). You could find the primes via the sieve of Eratosthenes or just download them from a list of primes.

Comment: If you allow downloading the primes, you should also allow downloading the answer !

Comment: http://gladhoboexpress.blogspot.com/2018/08/lcm.html

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, my simplification was flawed.  Nevertheless, your approach is inferior since it wastes time factoring numbers that don't need to be factored. In fact, as this answer demonstrates, factorization is not required at all.

Comment: @user3386109: you remark is not relevant. I said "you can implement a simple sieve" without more details so there is nothing you can conclude about "inferior".

Comment: @YvesDaoust You said *"producing the prime factorization of all numbers from 2 to 100"* There's absolutely no reason to do that.

Comment: @user3386109: I sustain my comment.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I maintain that your approach is inferior.

Comment: @YvesDaoust 16 isn't a number between 1 & 10 so why does it matter that 2520 isn't divisible by it?

Comment: @Dave: user3386109 removed his comment, for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

As 100 is small, you can work this out by producing the prime factorization of all numbers from 2 to 100 and keep the largest exponent of each prime among all factorizations. In fact, trying divisions by 2, 3, 5 and 7 will be enough to check primality up to 100, and there are just 25 primes to consider. You can implement a simple sieve to find the primes and perform the factorizations.

After you found all exponents of the prime decomposition of the lcm, you can either leave this as the answer, or perform the multiplications explicitly.

Comment: Note that if k is the max power of some prime p in the range then p^k is in [1,n] so you can limit this to maximal prime powers in the range and ignore other numbers.

Comment: @Dave: I think that this is implicit in the design of the algorithm and brings no simplification.